# transformations in iOS and particullary Scaling

Tags: ios, transformation, cgaffinetransform, cgaffinetransformscale

please correct me if I am wrong: if we have x=10, y=20, when we apply a transform on these coordinates (Lets say scaling x and y by 10), the new coordinates will be x=100 and y=200.
So, if we apply scaling of x by -1 we get x= -10, y =20. But why this action causes the view to be mirrored? shouldn't the view just be re-drawn at it's new coordinates?
What am I missing here ?

Comment: Remember to accept answers that solve your problems. I see that you have several questions with answers but none of them have been accepted. Accepting answers helps yourself and the other users of this site. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't think about a single coordinate, think about a range of coordinates.

If you take the coords (x-value only here) of... 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 and scale them by 10 then they will map to 0, 10, 20, 30, 40 respectively. This will stretch out the x axis and so the view will look 10 times bigger than it did originally.

If you take those same x coords and scale them by -1 then they will map to 0, -1, -2, -3, -4 respectively.

That is, the pixel that is furthest away from the origin (4) is still furthest away from the origin but now at -4.

Each pixel is mirrored through the origin.

That's how scaling works in iOS, Android and general mathematics.

If you just want to slide the view around without changing the size of it at all then you can use a `translation` instead.

Comment: what do you mean by stretch out the x axis ? It's good explanation but still something is not clear and I can't tell exactly what.

Comment: @DanielRahamim try thinking about just the number line. If you scale by 10 then it has the effect of stretching the number line so that the 1 is now 10 times further away from the 0 than it was originally. If you scale by -1 then the 1 is the same distance away from the 0 as it was but in the other direction.

Comment: @DanielRahamim take a look here. This explains it well... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rw7DBXZs_k0

Comment: Thanks, I will try it!